# Difference between this ES6 arrow function and regular function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Still new to ES6 so trying to understand why there's a difference between these two functions below. I'm working in React and am noticing that I'm getting an error when writing a non-ES6 function that sets state. This is happening within componentDidMount.

This way in ES6 works and returns what i need:

```
(pos) => this.setState({
    lat: pos.coords.latitude,
    lng: pos.coords.longitude,
  })
```

However, to this way throws an error - "Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function"

```
 function(pos) {
    this.setState({
      lat: pos.coords.latitude,
      lng: pos.coords.longitude
    })
  }
```

Aren't these the exact same thing? Can anyone explain why it would be throwing this error?

Here is the code from the react class to provide more context:

```
var GeolocationExample = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      lat: '',
      lng: '',
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(

      // Where I'm placing each of the above mentioned functions,

      (err) => alert(err.message),
    );
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Initial position: </Text>
          {this.state.lat}
        </Text>
        <Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Current position: </Text>
          {this.state.lng}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: as @Andrey pointed out: `Arrow functions have implicit this binding` so the non-arrow with `(function(pos){...}).bind(this)` should be equivalent to the arrow one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No they are not the same. Arrow functions are automatically bound to the context where they are created.
That means that

```
(x) => this.stuff = x
```

is (mostly) equivalent to:

```
(function(x) {
    return this.stuff = x;
}.bind(this))
```

Arrow functions will also preserve the `arguments`, `super` and `new.target` of the function inside which it is created.

Which means

```
(function a() {
  const u = () => console.log(arguments);
  u("whatever");
})("a args");
```

will print something like `["a args"]`.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation - greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's more to it that this, but this is a good intro. `arguments`, `super`, and `new.target` work in arrow functions. Arrow functions can also be created when there IS no `this` initialized yet, like in a class constructor before `super()` has been called.

Comment: Oh this is right. More exactly, just as with `this`, they preserve these values from the function where they are created. I actually did not know this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> ## Lexical this
>
> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own `this` value
>   (**a new object in case of a constructor**, undefined in strict mode
>   function calls, the context object if the function is called as an
>   "object method", etc.). This proved to be annoying with an
>   object-oriented style of programming.
>
> From : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

This is why, when you write:

```
 this.setState = function() {};
 function(pos) {
    this.setState({
      lat: pos.coords.latitude,
      lng: pos.coords.longitude
    })
  }
```

The `this` in `this.setState` inside the function is set to `{}` (an empty object).

When you write it with the `=>` notation instead, the this is shared with the outside of the function, which is equivalent to :

```
 this.setState = function() {};
 var self = this;
 function(pos) {
    self.setState({
      lat: pos.coords.latitude,
      lng: pos.coords.longitude
    })
  }
```

or you could also use `function(pos){ /* Stuff here */ }.bind(this);`

Comment: Thanks - very helpful!

Comment: "*This proved to be annoying with an object-oriented style of programming*" - wait what? Without `this`, object-oriented programming would hardly be possible like it is!

Comment: No, `this` in `setState` is *not* set to `{}`. Where did you get that from?

Comment: See thé link in my answer

Comment: This is wrong. It depends how your anonymous function is called. Here it seems it is not called at all (and because it is anonymous it will most likely never be).